# How to package and deploy cumulocity server-side agents?

Tags: cumulocity

We are creating a server-side agent which periodically fetches data from nodes and maps this data to cumulocity measurements, events.

What is an elegant approach for hosting and/or packaging such a server-side agent?

- We are hosting our own instance of the Cumulocity platform.
- It's preferable to keep this server-side agent as '*close*' to the core platform as possible, e.g. share some core agent framework dependencies.
- We'd like to limit the amount of setting up additional environments or containers (e.g. Tomcat).

Cumulocity uses Karaf, would it make any sense to deploy the server-side agent into Karaf as a bundle?

**Is there any recommended approach for hosting server-side agents?** Does the cumulocity platform offer an alternative to deploying the agent to some "own environment"?

The Cumulocity examples repository contains the "tracker-agent" server-side agent [example](https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-examples/src/daece0b445e154e36f85ac7194e10c6fd83bd8b0?at=default), which is an embedded tomcat Java application. There is little information about the intended deployment location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend deploying agents/microservices directly into the core Karaf server, since that endangers the resources available to the core APIs and is not supported. (I.e., will likely be overwritten with the next upgrade...)

Typically, people just provision an additional VM or docker next to Cumulocity to place their agents/microservices in. On top of that, we, for example, often use Spring Boot, so the effort is pretty low (java -jar ...).

We do have a hosting system for agents/microservices and will make that generally available also for others to use in Q1/2018. Follow the announcement channel at https://support.cumulocity.com to stay posted...